# How do I move one column to the right for each repeat of a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to input the data to column b go to column c so on

how i can do that here is my code please help me on this..

```
Sub () 

Dim Continue As String
Continue = "Go"

Do While Continue = "Go"

Dim Message As String
Dim Answer As String

Message = "enter name"
Answer =  inputbox(Message) 
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = (Answer)


If ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = "yes" then
activesheet.range("B10").value="good"
Else
ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value = "no good"
End If

Continue = InputBox("Do you want to continue?")
Loop

End Sub
```

Every time i loop ,it continues to insert the data in column b which i want in column c

Can you please edit my script..

thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code so it is easier to read.

Comment: What happens when C is substituted for B?

Comment: Then all of the data will be input in column C 

What i want is everytime the certain question is finish,then i will input again, it will input to another column

Comment: Hi karoline i already format it can you help me about my problem?what is your email address so i can email my codes to you

Comment: please explain exactly what you need, are you asking always `B2` and setting `B10` or should that looping?

Comment: (1) Your code gets a value for B1 from the user. How did B2 get to be "Yes"? (2) Do you want the first loop to use B1, B2 and B10; the second to use C1, C2 and C10; the third to use D1, D2 and D10 and so on?

Comment: Hi Tony,

Yes that's what i want can you show me the codes for that..

i really have no idea 

thank you so much in advance..

Comment: Here is the example..

I input the name then it should go to to A1
then i have some questions the answer is must go to A2 so on..

then what i want is for the next loop i want the name and the answers go to B1, B2 so on

Answer (score 0):

When you write: `ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = (Answer)`, “B1” is a literal; it will never change.

The parameter for `Range` is a String and you can build that string at run time:

```
Dim ColumnIdCrnt as String
Dim RowCrnt as Long

ColumnIdCrnt = "B"
RowCrnt = 1
ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnIdCrnt & RowCrnt).Value = (Answer)
```

This is not the easiest method but it is possible.

Rather than `Range` use `Cells`.  The syntax is `Cells(Row, Column)` where `Row` must be a row number and `Column` can either be a column identifier or a column number.  The following are all equivalent:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "B").Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value
```

The relationship between column numbers and column identifiers is: 1=”A”, 2=”B”, 3=”C”, 26=”Z”, 27=”AA” and so on.

So you could write something like this:

```
ColNumCrnt as Long

ColNumCrnt = 1

Do While Continue = "Go"
   ‘ Process input using column ColNumCrnt 

  ActiveSheet.Range(ColNumCrnt & "1").Value = (Answer)

  ColNumCrnt = ColNumCrnt + 1   ‘ Move one column to the right ready for next loop
Loop
```